# Change width ionic columns depending on the device

Tags: ionic-framework

I need make something like this example of boostrap grid system

```
 <!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
 </div>
```

Please help me!!

Comment: Ionic also have a grid component : http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid

Comment: But not has this feature.

Comment: If you scroll a little you can see responsive grid, isn't that what you are looking ? Also, you can import bootstrap grid in ionic !

Answer (score 0):

Use wrap in ion-row

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row wrap>
        <ion-col col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```